# How to copy the whole line in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, csv

How could I copy the whole line of a data frame? Using Pandas and Python

file.csv

gender;age;vaccinated
m;23;y
m;44;y
f;12;n
f;34;y
f;20;n

```
import pandas as pd

file = pd.read_csv("file.csv", encoding = "utf-8", sep=";")
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for line in file:
    if line['age'] < 18 and file['vaccinated'] == 'n':
    # how could I copy the whole line to the new dataframe [new_df] (including the gender information)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do all of this with just one line of code

```
import pandas as pd

file = pd.read_csv("file.csv", encoding = "utf-8", sep=";")
new_df = file.query('age < 18 and vaccinated == "n"')
```

Here is the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html?highlight=query#pandas.DataFrame.query) of the .query() function

By the way, when you are looping through the file you are looping through the column names, not through the rows. So what you get is ['gender', 'age', 'vaccinated']

Answer (score 0):

You can use boolean-indexing for selecting rows:

```py
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", encoding="utf-8", sep=";")

new_df = df[(df["age"] < 18) & (df["vaccinated"] == "n")]
print(new_df)
```

Prints:

```
  gender  age vaccinated
2      f   12          n
```